# Problems with PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

My code:

```
while ($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              $uri = 'https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/' . $row['tmdb_id'];
              $get = file_get_contents($uri);
              $pos1 = strpos($get, '<span class="genres">');
              $pos2 = strpos($get, '</span>', $pos1); 
              $text = substr($get,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1+7);

              if (strstr ($text, 'Animation'))
              array_push ($array, $row['poster_path']);
            }
```

it return me this error:

**failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
in "path/index.php" on line 128**

line 128 is: $get = file_get_contents($uri);

Comment: how many times is that code running? Since its inside a while loop that might be the cause.

Comment: `themoviedb.org` server doesn't like the number of requests you are making or the frequency.  You could try `sleep(1);` or something for the second case.

Comment: It is not a problem of `file_get_contents()`. Your code is hammering the target server and it has a protection layer that prevents it to be overwhelmed by flooding requests as yours. Add a 1 second delay on each iteration and it will probably serve your requests just fine.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro the code is that running 70 times. It give me a movies grid with gender "animation"

Comment: @AbraCadaver I used this code:

while.....

              ...if (strstr ($text, 'Animation'))
              array_push ($array, $row['poster_path']);

              sleep(1);
            }

...and the problem is same

Comment: Guys now the error is gone, but my web page doesn't load.

Answer (score 2):

Your target url is preventing this from happening. You're basically sending 70 requests in less than one second (probably). This is identified as an attack and at some point blocked.

You need to add some kind of timer to build some kind of queue that does this from time to time, instead of doing it all at once.

Comment: Yes, I used sleep(1) or sleep(10) but my page doesn't load. (the error is gone)

Comment: ah no, I have same error also with the function sleep();

Comment: Still the error is from what I said. Sleep will not solve your problem, because if you do sleep 10 then you'll end up with 70 seconds request and probably have a timeout error. Building a queue system for this task would be the proper way to go.